# Django get_or_create race condition when creating related objects

Tags: python, mysql, django, concurrency

I have an `ExtendedUser` model like this, that just points to Django's `User` model:

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

When a request comes in, I want to get or create an `User` and its related `ExtendedUser` if the user that I'm looking for doesn't exist. I have this code :

```
def get_or_create_user(username):
    with transaction.atomic():
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username=username,
            defaults={
                'first_name': "BLABLA",
            },
        )

        if created:
             extended_user = ExtendedUser()
             extended_user.user = user
             extended_user.save()

    return user
```

I wrap it inside a transaction, to be sure I don't create an `User` but not its associated `ExtendedUser`.

But, when two requests come in simultaneously that will create the same user, this fails from time to time with an `IntegrityError`, for both requests. So I end up with no user being created..

```
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'BLABLABLA' for key 'username'")
```

Note that I use MySQL, but I force `READ COMMITTED` isolation level.

What do I do wrong ? How should I handle this ? The models need to stay as they are.

Comment: create only if the record doesn't exists .. either by handling ObjectDoesNotExist exception or by checking exists() .

Comment: @SajiXavier this naive approach is the best way to have __more__ race conditions - a record can be inserted between when you check if it exists and when you try to create it. The whole point of `Queryset.get_or_create()` is actually to try and handle this situation, but it's alas not failsafe either.

Comment: As hard as the Django maintainers try to make `get_or_create` failsafe, there are indeed occasional issues. You could of course wrap the call in a try/except block, but for this concrete use case using the `post_save` signal as explained in Dalvtor's answer is the simplest and safest solution.

Comment: I don't see how `post_save` signal will help this problem at all.  Wrapping the `get_or_create` in a `try/except` is exactly what you need to do here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  according to the question both requests are failing with IntegrityError, so even signal handling will not work becuse User itself is not getting created. Maybe need to use table LOCK feature (i know LOCK works with postgreSQL)

Comment: @SajiXavier signals will work here, in that they will make sure an `ExtendedUser` is created whenever a `User` is created. This will of course not solve any race condition during User creation, indeed.

Comment: I don't think signals will work, as just after calling my `user = get_or_create_user(username)` function, then I try to access the `user.extendeduser`. So the `ExtendedUser` should be created at the same time as the `User`, so the slower query can retrieve it along with the `user`.. Plus I really want to make sure that one cannot be created without the other, which the signals don't guarantee me that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should solve this problem using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

After a User is saved, a signal will be fired. It is in the signal handler where you should create your ExtendedUser.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ExtendedUser.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: That's indeed the canonical solution here. Been using it in a dozen projects without any issue.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all, which is `IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'BLABLABLA' for key 'username'")` on the `get_or_create` call.  This is a wrong use of signals, which are for _decoupling separate apps_ rather than chaining a series of always-required actions together.

Comment: This will not work, as just after calling my `user = get_or_create_user(username)` function, then I try to access the `user.extendeduser`. So the `ExtendedUser` should be created at the same time as the `User`, so the slower query can retrieve it along with the `user`.

Comment: @fougerejo this WILL work. Django's `signals` are NOT async, so the the ExtendedUser is garanteed to have been created when `User.objects.create()` returns. I've been using this for years on dozen projects without a single issue. This wont of course solve the occasional race condition, though - but I'm afraid there's actually no 101% failsafe solution with MySQL here.

Comment: Ok I see. But then at the end, what's the difference between using signals and creating the ExtendedUser right away?